# Subtracting time with moment.js not giving correct output

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I am working with moment.js and when I subtract the two times with it then its not giving the correct output. In the following example I want the output as `00:45` but it gives me `12:45`.

```
var secondPunchOut = "01:00 PM";
var secondPunchIn = "12:15 PM";
var secondDifference = moment.utc(moment(secondPunchOut, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment.utc(moment(secondPunchIn, "HH:mm:ss")))).format("HH:mm")

var secondDifference = moment(secondPunchOut, 'h:mm A').subtract(moment(secondPunchIn, 'h:mm A')).format('h:mm');
```

Output: `12:45`

Comment: If you really are expecting 45 mins secondPunchOut should be 13:00 PM.

Comment: The output is correct, you just need to show it in a 24h clock format, `HH:mm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct, you just need to show it in a 24h clock format, as there is no `00:00` in a 12h clock. Try this:

```
var secondDifference = moment(secondPunchOut, 'h:mm A')
    .subtract(moment(secondPunchIn, 'h:mm A')) 
    .format('HH:mm'); // Note the format change.
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nz1hm9Lr/)